# have_content and have_selector don't work with Capybara and Minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, minitest

I switched from `RSpec` to `Minitest` recently. My model tests are all running great. However, my integration tests are no longer working.

None of my calls to `have_content` or `have_selector` are working.

I have included `Capybara::DSL` as follows in my `test_helper.rb` file:

```
class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers # for x_path and x_url helpers
  include Capybara::DSL
  include PossibleJSDriver # switching Capybara driver for javascript tests

  def setup
  end

end
```

Here's the offending line in the test:

```
page.should have_selector('ul.ui-autocomplete li.ui-menu-item a')
```

and the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `have_selector' for #<AppIntegrationTest:0x007f95f103afc8>
```

I don't understand why these don't work anymore. I am using the `minitest-rails-capybara` gem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is different in Minitest. Use this instead:

```
page.must_have_selector('ul.ui-autocomplete li.ui-menu-item a')
```